# vstest.console.exe not generating Test Attributes (Owner, Priority, TestCategory) in .trx file

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, mstest, vstest, trx

I have test methods which are given attributes like Owner, Priority, TestCategory as follows

```
<TestMethod()>
<Owner("Madhu")>
<Priority(1)>
<TestCategory("MyCategory")>
Public Sub SampleTest()
    Assert.AreEqual("0", "0")
End Sub
```

When I run this test using MSTest.exe these arrtibutes are appearing in generated trx file where as if I run with VSTest.console.exe they are not coming.

I have checked the vstest comands, I could not find one for this.

Am I missing anything, or this feature itself doesn't exist in vstest ?